# (Yii2) GridVIew "clean" url querystring upon form submission

Tags: gridview, yii2, query-string

Within a view I have a GridView and an ActiveForm. Both for the same $modelSearch.

Search is enabled in GridView, so you can search in both the GridView and in the ActiveForm.

Given a "clean" URI like: `/index.php?r=customer%2Findex`

If you submit GridView the URI becomes: `/index.php?r=customer%2Findex&someGridViewParams%5D=`

Then if you submit ActiveForm the URI becomes: `/index.php?r=customer%2Findex&someActiveFormParams%5D=`

Then now that the URI is "dirty" with form submission params, If you submit GridView the URI becomes: `/index.php?someGridViewParams%5D=&r=customer%2Findex%someActiveFormParams%5D=`

See?
I need that GridView generates a URI from scratch without any previous querystring params. Otherwise it is producing a different query.

The issue may be related to this: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/668/form-with-get-method-causes-repeated-stacking-of-url-parameters/

Comment: If you want to combine the 2 searches then you should leave it like that. That is the way the search mode will know how to search on both. Do you want the 2 searches to work independently?

Comment: According to what i described, which is what i am experiencing, i can tell GridView's search (works in conjunction with / depends on) ActiveForm. While ActiveForm works alone (is independant). But yes, i want them both to work indepently.